# Python web scraper for Target

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm a novice programmer trying to deploy a python web scraper for Target.com. I've pasted the code below.

The issue I'm trying to solve is that when I run the script, no csv file is created at the conclusion. The web browser opens and data is running down sublime text, so I'm confused as to why the output.csv doesn't appear.

I'd greatly appreciate the help. Thank you!

```
import requests
import csv
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import html


cats = [
    ('Natural Laundry Detergent','https://www.target.com/c/natural-cleaning-supplies-household-essentials/-/N-4yjz7Z55t1q?Nao=0'),
    ('Natural All-Purpose Cleaner','https://www.target.com/c/natural-cleaning-supplies-household-essentials/-/N-4yjz7Zzag5n?Nao=0'),
    ('Natural Dish Soaps','https://www.target.com/c/natural-cleaning-supplies-household-essentials/-/N-4yjz7Zx6dg5?Nao=0'),
    ('Natural Hair Shampoo','https://www.target.com/c/natural-hair-care/-/N-4smdrZ56ecv?Nao=0'),
    ('Natural Hair Conditioner','https://www.target.com/c/natural-hair-care/-/N-4smdrZv1cqo?Nao=0'),
    ('Natural Body Wash','https://www.target.com/c/natural-personal-care/-/N-4smdpZ5td3p?Nao=0'),
    ('Baby Shampoo and Body Wash','https://www.target.com/c/baby-toiletries-bath-potty/-/N-5xtjdZ54wt4?Nao=0'),
    ('Baby Bath Wash' ,'https://www.target.com/c/baby-toiletries-bath-potty/baby-bath-wash/-/N-5xtjdZ5ri3m'),
    ('Baby Bubble Bath' ,'https://www.target.com/c/baby-toiletries-bath-potty/-/N-5xtjdZ5t3hx?Nao=0'),
    ('Stain Removers', 'https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=stain+remover&facetedValue=56cpg&Nao=0'),
    ('Baby Lotions', 'https://www.target.com/c/baby-toiletries-bath-potty/baby-lotions/-/N-5xtjdZ5vg2t'),
    ('Tampons','https://www.target.com/c/tampons-feminine-products-personal-care/-/N-4y634'),
    ('Maxi Pads','https://www.target.com/c/maxi-pads-feminine-products-personal-care/-/N-4y633'),
    ('Feminine Hygiene','https://www.target.com/c/feminine-hygiene-products-personal-care/-/N-4y631'),
]


class TargetClient(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\wquar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\chromedriver.exe')
        self.base_url = 'https://www.target.com'

    def gather_product_links(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.wd.page_source)
        divs = soup.select('div[class*="ProductCardImageWrapper"]')
        links = [self.base_url + d.a['href'] for d in divs]
        return links

    def goto_next_page(self):
        ele = self.wd.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='next page']")
        ele.click()
        time.sleep(1.5)


    def _format_product_name(self,input):
        out = input.replace('®','').replace('\x99','')
        return out

    def _format_brand_name(self,input):
        out = input.replace('®','').replace('\x99','')
        out = html.unescape(out)

        if out == "Murphy's":
            out = 'Murphy'
        elif out == 'ECOS by Earth Friendly Products':
            out = 'Ecos'
        elif out == 'Eden Body Works':
            out = 'EDEN BodyWorks'
        elif out == 'BRÖÖ':
            out = 'BRöö'
        elif out == 'Love Beauty & Planet':
            out = 'Love Beauty And Planet'
        elif out == 'Hask':
            out = 'HASK'
        elif out == 'Palmers':
            out = "Palmer's"
        elif out == 'MacVoil':
            out = "Macvoil"
        elif out == 'Dear Clark,':
            out = "Dear Clark"
        elif out == 'Earth Science Naturals':
            out = "Earth Science"
        elif out == 'PAW Patrol':
            out = "Paw Patrol"
        elif out == 'up & up™':
            out = "Up&Up"
        elif out == 'Johnson & Johnson':
            out = "Johnson's"
        elif out == 'Earth Mama Angel Baby':
            out = "Earth Mama"
        elif out == 'Mielle Organics':
            out = "Mielle"
        elif out == 'EveryDay Coconut':
            out = "Alaffia"
        elif out == 'Olivina':
            out = "OLIVINA MEN"
        elif out == 'AVALON':
            out = "Avalon"
        elif out == 'Oxi Clean':
            out = "OxiClean"
        elif out == 'Village Naturals':
            out = "Nourishing Naturals"
        elif out == 'everyone':
            out = "everyone"
        elif out == 'Savannah Bee Company':
            out = 'Savannah Bee'
        elif out == 'Camille Rose Natural':
            out = 'Camille Rose'

        return out

    def _get_product_name(self, complete_product_name, brand_name):
        if brand_name == 'Alaffia':
            return complete_product_name.split(' -')[0].strip()
        elif brand_name == 'SoCozy' and 'So Cfl ozy' in complete_product_name:
            return complete_product_name.split('So Cfl ozy')[1].split(' -')[0].strip()
        elif brand_name == 'Ecos' and 'ECOS' in complete_product_name:
            return complete_product_name.split('ECOS')[1].split(' -')[0].strip()
        elif brand_name == 'Clorox 2' and 'Clorox2' in complete_product_name:
            return complete_product_name.split('Clorox2')[1].split(' -')[0].strip()

        product_name = complete_product_name.split(brand_name)[1].split(' -')[0].strip()
        return product_name

    def scrape_product_page(self, url, category):
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
        d = {}

        try:
            complete_product_name = soup('span',attrs={'data-test':'product-title'})[0].text
        except:
            print('ERROR')
            return None

        complete_product_name = self._format_product_name(complete_product_name)

        print(complete_product_name)

        brand_name = soup.select('div[class*="ProductDetailsTitle"]')[0].text.split('Shop all')[-1].strip()
        brand_name = self._format_brand_name(brand_name)

        d['Brand'] = brand_name

        #return (complete_product_name, brand_name)

        try:
            product_name = self._get_product_name(complete_product_name,brand_name)
        except:
            print('PRODUCT ERROR')
            print('PRODUCT ERROR')
            return None

        d['Product'] = product_name

        try:
            d['Capacity'] = soup('b',text='Capacity (Volume):')[0].next.next.strip()
        except:
            d['Capacity'] = self._parse_capacity_from_title(complete_product_name)

        try:
            d['Scent'] = soup('b',text='Scent:')[0].next.next.strip()
        except:
            d['Scent'] = ''

        try:
            d['Price'] = soup('div',attrs={'data-test':'product-price'})[0].span.text
        except:
            d['Price'] = ''

        try:
            d['Product Form'] = soup('b',text='Product Form:')[0].next.next.strip()
        except:
            d['Product Form'] = ''

        try:
            star_rating =soup('div',attrs={'data-ref':'rating-mask'})[0].attrs['style'].split('width:')[1]
            d['Star Rating'] = round(float(star_rating.split('%')[0]) / 20, 2)
        except:
            d['Star Rating']=''

        try:
            d['Number of Ratings'] = soup('span',attrs={'data-test':'ratingCount'})[0].text.strip()
            if d['Number of Ratings'] == 'be the first!':
                d['Number of Ratings'] = 0
        except:
            d['Number of Ratings'] = ''

        try:
            d['Health Facts'] = soup('b',text='Health Facts:')[0].next.next.strip()
        except:
            d['Health Facts'] = ''

        try:
            d['Features'] = soup('b',text='Features:')[0].next.next.strip()
        except:
            d['Features'] = ''

        try:
            d['Wellness Standard'] = soup('b',text='Wellness Standard:')[0].next.next.strip()
        except:
            d['Wellness Standard'] = ''

        try:
            d['Sustainability Claims'] = soup('b',text='Sustainability Claims:')[0].next.next.strip()
        except:
            d['Sustainability Claims'] = ''


        try:
            d['Number of Uses'] = soup('b',text='Number of uses:')[0].next.next.strip()
        except:
            d['Number of Uses'] = self._parse_num_uses_from_title(complete_product_name)


        try:
            d['UPC Code'] = soup('b',text='UPC')[0].next.next.next.next.strip()
        except:
            d['UPC Code'] = ''

        d['URL'] = url
        d['Category'] = category
        d['Package Quantity'] = self._parse_quant_from_title(complete_product_name)

        return d

    def _parse_capacity_from_title(self,input):
        m = re.search('\d+(\.\d)? ?(fl)? ?oz',input,re.IGNORECASE)

        if m:
            return m.group()
        return ''

    def _parse_quant_from_title(self,input):
        m = re.search('\d+ ?pk',input)

        if m:
            return m.group().split('pk')[0].strip()
        return 1

    def _parse_num_uses_from_title(self,input):
        m = re.search('\d+ ?ct',input)
        if m:
            return m.group().split('ct')[0]
        return ''

    def scrape_cat(self, cat_name, url):
        h = []
        self.wd.get(url)
        links = self.gather_all_product_links()
        for l in links:
            print (l)
            res = self.scrape_product_page(l, cat_name)
            h.append(res)
        return h

    def gather_all_product_links(self):
        links = self.gather_product_links()
        while True:
            try:
                self.goto_next_page()
                links.extend(self.gather_product_links())
            except:
                return [l for l in list(set(links)) if '-category-' not in l]

def main():
    h = []
    targ = TargetClient()
    for cat_name, url in cats:
        data = targ.scrape_cat(cat_name, url)
        h.extend(data)
    return h
    write_csv(data)

def write_csv(data):
    data = [x for x in data if x]
    f = open('output.csv','w')
    fields = ['Category','Brand', 'Product', 'Scent', 'Price','Package Quantity','Product Form', 'Capacity', 'Number of Uses', 'Star Rating', 'Number of Ratings', 'Health Facts', 'Features', 'Wellness Standard', 'Sustainability Claims', 'UPC Code', 'URL'] 
    dw = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fields)
    dw.writeheader()
    dw.writerows(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Update: Printing to csv issue resolved. New problem is that no Price data is being recorded...help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put write_csv call before your return in your main() function.

Like that :

```
def main():
    h = []
    targ = TargetClient()
    for cat_name, url in cats:
        data = targ.scrape_cat(cat_name, url)
        h.extend(data)
        write_csv(data)        
    return h
```

Hope its help.

Comment: Ok thank you. Now the csv file is created, but I have another question: the script is only writing data for the last category I define in "cats" at the top (Feminine Hygiene) and it is not capturing any price data. Is it clear why that is happening? Thanks again

Comment: Yes it's normal. It's because you have to put write_csv() function in your loop. I edited my answer for you.

Comment: thanks so much for the quick response...I made that change but still only getting data for the Feminine Hygeine category and the Price data fields are all blank...any other ideas? I'm all ears!